# How to get the random forest threshold from an h2o random forest object

Tags: python, random-forest, h2o

I have an h2o random forest in Python. How to extract for each tree the threshold of each features ?

My aim is to implement this random forest in c++

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you could download and take a look at the POJO which lists all the thresholds used for the model `h2o.download_pojo(model, path=u'', get_jar=True, jar_name=u'')`

Comment: Yes but I have 120 trees and 40 features.... impossible I need something more industrial